# Fat Tailed risks: do they get fatter when we linearize non-linear systems?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, data-mining, kurtosis, risk

I'm concerned about the risks that might arise when one decide to model a complex process into a linear or non-linear polynomial or maybe a state space model.

In the beginning of the century, Maxwell showed that the governors that were used to control motors caused sometimes a failure for the latter. These events are associated with Fat Tailed risks. I'm assuming that the same heuristic might be true in modelling complex processes (e.g. Industrial Processes such as Nuclear Reactor) into linear or non-linear polynomials.

My question: are there any papers that describe such behavior? Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely! There are many, such as for example:

[Ahlfeld R, Belkouchi B, Montomoli F, 2016, SAMBA: Sparse Approximation of Moment-Based Arbitrary Polynomial Chaos, Journal of Computational Physics, Vol:320, ISSN:0021-9991, Pages:1-16](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021999116301516)

[Montomoli FF, Amirante DD, Hills NN, Shahpar SS, Massini MM. Uncertainty Quantification, Rare Events, and Mission Optimization: Stochastic Variations of Metal Temperature During a Transient. ASME. J. Eng. Gas Turbines Power. 2014;137(4):042101-042101-9. doi:10.1115/1.4028546](http://gasturbinespower.asmedigitalcollection.asme.org/article.aspx?articleid=1905933)

Ahlfeld R, Montomoli F, Scalas E, Shahpar S, 2016, Uncertainty Quantification for Fat-Tailed Probability Distributions in Aircraft Engine Simulations, Journal of Propulsion and Power

[Montomoli, F and Massini, M, Gas turbines and uncertainty quantification: Impact of PDF tails on UQ predictions, the Black Swan, GT2013-94306, ASME Turbo Expo 2013](http://proceedings.asmedigitalcollection.asme.org/proceeding.aspx?articleid=1776261)

Note that there's nothing inherently wrong in using polynomials to model Fat-Tailed risk - the problem is in the pdf of the predictors. Consider a lognormal distribution: strictly speaking this is not **fat-tailed**, since the tail goes to zero faster than a power, but just **heavy-tailed** (the tail goes to zero slower than an exponential). The log-normal distribution has an associated family of orthogonal polynomials, but as described in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/198482/58675), they are not dense in the space of mean-square integrable functions. This means that expanding the response of a complex system, whose input variables are log-normally distributed, in a series of polynomials which are orthogonal w.r.t. the log-normal measure, is not a good idea: the expansion may not converge or converge to a limit which is not actually the response function of the system.

However, even with a fat-tailed distribution of the inputs (for example the Cauchy distribution), you can still define numerically a set of polynomials which are orthogonal to the input distribution, as long as you truncate the distribution to some limit. This is an approximation, of course, but it could make sense. Example: you want to model the possibility of a temperature spike at the inlet of a gas turbine nozzle. It might make sense to assume that rare events (very high temperature spikes) have a frequency which is much higher than expected, if the distribution of temperature spikes were Gaussian. Thus, you may want to use a lognormal, t-Student or Cauchy distribution (t-Student with 1 degree of freedom). On the other hand, you clearly don't need to model the risk posed by spikes of, say, $10^4 \ °K$: even if, from a theoretical point of view, the untruncated Cauchy distribution would give a "high" (w.r.t. a Normal distribution) probability of such spikes, in practice there's no way at all that you would reach a temperature of $10^4 \ °K$ inside a gas turbine, except pheraps if the gas turbine were hit by an atomic bomb :) Thus, you can safely truncate the Cauchy to a limit which is sufficienly higher than any physically plausible temperature, but lower than $\infty$.

Comment: Except that if someone didn't take into consideration the modeling of Fat tail risks. My main concern is that Linear Optimization lead to higher frequency of Fat Tailed risks, unlike a human controlled manner (which is a random fashion). Thus the question: should we optimize linearly complex systems or should we optimize in a random manner (tinkering). An analogy would be Diet versus Random Fasting (food).

Comment: No, in the papers above they model precisely that risk. The mention of "Black Swans" and "Fat-tailed probability distributions" straight into the titles of the papers, should suggest you that they modeled that risk. I don't get your point.

Comment: My point isn't about how to model Fat Tailed risks but with this simple idea: "Are Fat Tails "Fatter" in a linearly optimized system than the Fat Tails in a non-optimized system"?

Comment: Linear optimization (I guess you mean [Linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming)) is not the same as "modeling complex processes [..] into linear or non-linear polynomials". If you were referring specifically to linear optimization, then this is a different question from what you wrote originally, and I suggest you modify your question to clarify that. [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] w.r.t. your new question, I can only say that optimizing the reliability of an engineering system based on FORM (thus, linearizing the limit state function and assuming that input are normally distributed) will lead to a nonrobust system (i.e., actual probability of failure higher than estimated). If I remember well, one of the linked papers should show the results of an optimization where the system is not linearized, and the inputs are given a fat tail distribution instead than a Gaussian one.

Comment: yes exactly this is what i was looking for and I'll update my question. In fact, as you said, sometimes we linearize non-linear systems so we can be able to use LP techniques but we forget completely about the increase of Fat tailed risks in such conditions.

Answer (score 1):

In the paper ([Uryasev, 2000](http://www.ise.ufl.edu/uryasev/files/2011/11/FinNews.pdf)) was introduced a new risk measure - Conditional Value-at-Risk (CVaR). I think you can use the CVaR as a measure of fat tail risk.

**Reference**

Uryasev, S. (2000),  Conditional Value-at-Risk: Optimization Algorithms and Applications. Financial Engineering News, No. 14, February, 2000, 1-5.